# Change Background Color of ViewController Swift? (Single View Application)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am making a very simple single view application in Swift (XCode 6.2) that comprises of 2 buttons "blackButton" and "whiteButton". Upon clicking blackButton it changes the View's background color to Black and upon clicking the whiteButton it changes the background to white. Can anyone suggest any possible ways to do this?

#### ViewController.swift:

```
//beginning
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func blackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    @IBAction func whiteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A view controller's view can be accessed through it's `view` property, which is just a regular `UIView`.  `UIView`'s have a `backgroundColor` property, which is a `UIColor` and controls the color of the view.

```
@IBAction func blackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   view.backgroundColor = .black
}

@IBAction func whiteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 color is simply UIColor.white

Comment: Or even simpler .white

Answer (score 7):

> For Custom Colors

```
@IBAction func blackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let blackColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.backgroundColor = blackColor 
 }

@IBAction func whiteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let whiteColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.backgroundColor = whiteColor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Color Literal. Easily to customize your own colors.

```
@IBAction func blackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.backgroundColor = ColorLiteral   //Custom color
}

@IBAction func whiteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.backgroundColor = ColorLiteral   //Custom color
}
```